# Regex for a 19 character string that includes special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a regex that limits a string to 19 or 15 characters and also includes special character but out of order.

Examples are

```
847294729472903472c3c
 111 ( 3234) 3235
1234 + 1234
```

Comment: What is a special character?

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what? Have you already looked up the format of regular expressions? If so, what parts confused you? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: by special characters he must mean : `metacharacters` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference

Answer (score -1):

If a special character is any non-ascii letter or integer number, you can do the following:

```cs
new Regex("^((.{15})|(.{19}))$").IsMatch(text) && new Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9]").IsMatch(text)
```

See on .NET fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/vTyn7q

Comment: It'd probably be better to use `(text.Length == 15 || text.Length == 19)` for the first part as that is more obvious as to its intent.